# SSIS - Event Handler - Email Error Code and Description

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create an SSIS package that consumes a text file and places the contents in a table.  I have the main flow working correctly but i am now looking at some error handling.  I created an Event handler for the "OnError" event.  I put a mail task in there and configured it to send some text and it worked properly.  What i want to do now is configure it to send a variable.  I changed the message source type to variable and created a string variable.  The variable expression is this:

```
 "The process to load the data failed.  Please see the logs:   Error Code: " +  (DT_WSTR, 20) @[System::ErrorCode]
```

But when the handler grabs the error it sits there processing and never finishes.

Can you please give me some advice on how to properly configure this?

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: Which OnError event?  The one for the load task or the whole package?

Comment: I have tried it on both.  Neither seem to work.

Comment: Verify that you don't have any breakpoints active.  Pull down the Debug menu and click "Delete all Breakpoints".

Comment: This sounds like the variable is getting locked by another process, like the task itself.  Perhaps you can use a precedence constraint, instead, and keep the smtp task in the control flow rather than the event handler.  You won't have the error code, but the flow of the code will be more clear.